# How to make UITableView not change imageView's frame, or resize the image to fill the frame size?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview

In `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`, I am setting `imageView.image` to a 1x1, or 60x60 placeholder image, while the cell's height is 300.  I also set `imageView.frame` to `(0,0, 300, 300)`.

Then I call a method `downloadImageFromURL:andSetIntoCell`, which immediately add a `UIActivityIndicatorView` and set the frame to `(0,0, 300, 300)`  (the download is done asynchronously in a thread, and the method won't wait for the download but just return immediately).

However, after `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` return the cell, `imageView.frame` is adjusted to vertically center the image of original 60x60 size.  If that placeholder image is 800x800, it actually works fine: the frame is still (0,0, 300, 300) and the image is scaled down, but when the image is 60x60, the frame is actually adjusted to something like (0,120, 60, 60), that is ok because the placeholder is transparent, but the `UIActivityIndicatorView` was added as a subview of `imageView`, and therefore get pushed down vertically, having a height of 300 and cover up part of the next row.

Is there a way to tell `UITableView` not to change `imageView.frame`, or easily resize the image to 300x300 programmatically (preferably not to use BitmapContext), or tell `imageView` to scale to fill the frame?

I added:

```
cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
```

after setting `imageView.frame`, which normally works if I am drawing on a UIView, but UITableView will still show the original 60x60 size, and adjust `imageView.frame` to vertically center it.

(I think in this case I can just make `UIActivityIndicatorView` the size of the image: 60x60, but supposedly it is to do it with a 1x1 transparent placeholder image)

**Update: by the way, I even added:**

```
self.table.autoresizesSubviews = NO;
self.table.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;

cell.autoresizesSubviews = NO;
cell.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;

cell.imageView.autoresizesSubviews = NO;
cell.imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
```

before the cell is returned, and it is the same: the imageView is repositioned and resized.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Are you able to solve this, if yes then how?

Answer (score 0):

The frames of cell's imageview is not changing later on. So using `layoutSubviews`, I resolve this matter as follows:-

Set the image using `AFNetworking`'s method named `setImageWithURLRequest:` I use the 64*64 size for my example. You can *alter the frames* which are applicable to your table view.

```
NSURL *urlMapThumbnail = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=8&size=65x65&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:red%7Clabel:S%7C28.5002761,77.08126909999999"];

__weak UITableViewCell *cellTemp = cell;
[cell.imageView setImageWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlMapThumbnail]
                      placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sotrelocation"]
                               success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
                                   CGSize finalSize = CGSizeMake(64, 64);
                                   image = [UIImage imageWithImage:image scaledToSize:finalSize];
                                   cellTemp.imageView.image = image;
                                   [cellTemp layoutSubviews];
                               } failure:nil];
```

*//Method to re-scale the image size*

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    //UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```