# On iOS, if SDWebImage has no placeholder, then the image won't show?

Tags: ios, uitableview, sdwebimage

If the code does inside of `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:
     [NSURL URLWithString:
         [NSString stringWithFormat:
              @"http://www.mysite.com/images/pic%i.png", 
              indexPath.row % 12]]];
```

with no placeholder, the image won't show?  (if a placeholder is used, then it will show).

I tried setting `cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300);` beforehand and it still won't show it.  If I use the longer version `setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:success:failure:` and use a placeholder of `nil`, and use in the success block `[cell setNeedsLayout];`, then the image will show (but cannot be contained in the 300x300 box if `cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300);` is used before calling `setNeedsLayout`  It may be 400 x 300 or 500 x 300 depending on image width).  But what about the short form -- can it be made to work?

Comment: What do you mean by short term? It sounds like you already have a solution using the success / failure blocks? This is the same issue really that we discussed a couple of days ago: [On iOS, how to make a cell.imageView refresh its content?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12209380/on-ios-how-to-make-a-cell-imageview-refresh-its-content/12209846#12209846). In UITableViewCell's implementation of `layoutSubviews` it appears it sets its `imageView`'s frame to `(0,0,0,0)` if its image is nil. So if the placeholder is nil, at layout time the resize happens.

Comment: The short form meaning the most basic usage of SDWebImage -- the very first example in the question: `setImageWithURL`.  It is supposed to work, isn't it?  Or it will not work at all in a UITableView?

Comment: If it gives you no opportunity to pass blocks / provide delegates for callbacks, and you don't want to subclass UITableViewCell to work around the issue (e.g., restoring `self.imageView.frame` if `super` changed it to `(0,0,0,0)`, then I would expect the short form wouldn't meet your needs.

Comment: aha, I guess I don't yet fully grasp the "auto layout mechanism" yet, so that's why the question, and this looks weird too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212565/how-to-make-uitableview-not-change-imageviews-frame-or-resize-the-image-to-fil